# error: expected '}' before 'else'

Tags: arduino

i'm trying to build a board that sounds a speaker when a button is pressed, i am completely lost and i'm pretty new to arduino and coding in general. This is my first project that i'm working on without tutorials or anything so if the coding is a little messy i'm sorry. Thanks in advance!

```
  #include "pitches.h"

int sensorPin = 0;
int val = 9;

int Buzzer1 = 2;

int buttonState1 = 1;
int buttonState2 = 5;
int buttonState3 = 6;
int buttonState4 = 7;

const int buttonPlay = 1; 
const int buttonBlue = 5;
const int buttonGreen = 6;
const int buttonYellow = 7;

const int greenLight = 13;
const int yellowLight1 = 12;
const int yellowLight2 = 11;
const int redLight = 10;

int melody[] = { //SECRET SONG
  NOTE_E5, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_C5, 
  NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E3, NOTE_E5,
  NOTE_E3, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_B2, 
  NOTE_C3, NOTE_D3, NOTE_D5, NOTE_F5, NOTE_A5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_G5, 
  NOTE_F5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_C3, 0, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_G4, NOTE_E5, 
  NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A4, 0, 
  NOTE_E5, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_C5, 
  NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E3, NOTE_E5,
  NOTE_E3, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_B2, 
  NOTE_C3, NOTE_D3, NOTE_D5, NOTE_F5, NOTE_A5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_G5, 
  NOTE_F5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_C3, 0, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_G4, NOTE_E5, 
  NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A4, 0,
  NOTE_E4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_C4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_D4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3,
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_GS3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_E4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_C4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_D4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3,
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_E4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_GS4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3,
  NOTE_E5, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_C5, 
  NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E3, NOTE_E5,
  NOTE_E3, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_B2, 
  NOTE_C3, NOTE_D3, NOTE_D5, NOTE_F5, NOTE_A5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_G5, 
  NOTE_F5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_C3, 0, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_G4, NOTE_E5, 
  NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A4, 0, 
  NOTE_E5, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_C5, 
  NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E3, NOTE_E5,
  NOTE_E3, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_B2, 
  NOTE_C3, NOTE_D3, NOTE_D5, NOTE_F5, NOTE_A5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_G5, 
  NOTE_F5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_C3, 0, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_G4, NOTE_E5, 
  NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A4, 0,
  NOTE_E4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_C4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_D4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3,
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_GS3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_E4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_C4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_D4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_B3, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3,
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_E4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_A2, NOTE_E3, 
  NOTE_GS4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3, NOTE_GS2, NOTE_E3,
};

int noteDurations[] = { //SECRET SONG NOTE DURATIONS
 8,8,8,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
  8,4,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,
  8,8,8,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
  8,4,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,
  8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
  8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
  8,8,8,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
  8,4,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,
  8,8,8,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
  8,4,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,
  8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
  8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
};


void setup() {

  { //OUTPUTS
  pinMode(greenLight, OUTPUT); //Green Wire PIN13
  pinMode(yellowLight1, OUTPUT); //Yellow Wire PIN12
  pinMode(yellowLight2, OUTPUT); //Yellow Wire PIN11
  pinMode(redLight, OUTPUT); //Yellow Wire PIN10
  pinMode(Buzzer1, OUTPUT); //Black Wire PIN2
  }

  { //INPUTS
  pinMode(buttonPlay, INPUT); //Green Wire PIN1
  pinMode(buttonBlue, INPUT); //Blue Wire PIN5
  pinMode(buttonGreen, INPUT); //Green Wire PIN6
  pinMode(buttonYellow, INPUT); //White Wire PIN7
  }
}

 void loop() {
  {  //BUTTON STATES
    buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPlay);
    buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonBlue);
    buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonGreen);
    buttonState4 = digitalRead(buttonYellow);
  }

    {  //SECRET SONG
      if(buttonState1 == LOW,buttonState3 == LOW){
for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 1000; thisNote++){
    int noteDuration = 1000/noteDurations[thisNote];
    tone(2, melody[thisNote],noteDuration);
    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
    delay(pauseBetweenNotes);   
    noTone(2); //stop the tone playing:
  }
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
      }
    }

   { //READPOTENTIOMETER
    val = analogRead(sensorPin);
    delay(10);
   }

  { //BUTTONBLUE
    if(buttonState2 == LOW){
      tone(Buzzer1,200,100);
    }
  }

  { //BUTTONGREEN
if(buttonState3 == LOW){
      if(val < 225){tone(Buzzer1,400,250);
     }else{if(val >= 225,val < 510){tone(Buzzer1,350,225);
     }}else{if(val >= 510,val < 735){tone(Buzzer1,300,200);
     }}else{if(val >= 735){tone(Buzzer1,250,175);
     }}
     }
  }

  { //BUTTONYELLOW
    if(buttonState4 == LOW){

     }
  }

  { //LIGHTGREEN
    if(val < 255){
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    }
  }

  { //LIGHTYELLOW1
    if(val > 255){
      digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  }
    else{ digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    }
  }
  { //LIGHTYELLOW2
        if(val > 510){
      digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  }
    else{ digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    }
  }
{ //LIGHTRED
         if(val > 765){
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  }
    else{ digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    }
}
 }
```

Full error code:

```
Good_Meme.ino: In function 'void loop()':
Good_Meme:144: error: expected '}' before 'else'
      }}else{if(val >= 510,val < 735){tone(Buzzer1,300,200);
        ^
Good_Meme:145: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
      }}else{if(val >= 735){tone(Buzzer1,250,175);
        ^
Good_Meme.ino: At global scope:
Good_Meme:150: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
   { //BUTTONYELLOW
   ^
expected '}' before 'else'
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, your if/else nestings in the *BUTTONGREEN* segment are incorrect.  Let's block your `if` structure so that it's easier to read...

```
if(buttonState3 == LOW)
{
    if(val < 225)
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,400,250);
    }
    else
    {
        if(val >= 225,val < 510)
        {
            tone(Buzzer1,350,225);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(val >= 510,val < 735)
        {
            tone(Buzzer1,300,200);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(val >= 735)
        {
            tone(Buzzer1,250,175);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see, you're basically saying, "if this, then that.  Else, something else.  Else, something else.  Else, something else."  You can only have one `else` statement in an `if`, because it will be treated as the "final solution" in your logic (if all else fails, do [this]).

So, I think what you want to do is reformat this to use `else if` logic.  I *believe* a more correct structure would be:

```
if(buttonState3 == LOW)
{
    if(val < 225)
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,400,250);
    }
    else if (val >= 225,val < 510)
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,350,225);
    }
    else if(val >= 510,val < 735)
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,300,200);
    }
    else if(val >= 735)
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,250,175);
    }
}
```

***But!!!*** On that last `else if` condition, you might be able to change that to just `else` and leave out the `if(val >= 735)`.  Because, at the end of the road, if you've gotten that far, you can pretty much be sure that `val >= 735`.  Also, you could consider removing the first part of your `else if` condition.  Because, if you're in your second condition (`(val >= 225, val < 510)`), you already know that `val >= 225`.  So, you *should* be able to say:

```
if(buttonState3 == LOW)
{
    if(val < 225)
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,400,250);
    }
    else if (val < 510)
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,350,225);
    }
    else if(val < 735)
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,300,200);
    }
    else
    {
        tone(Buzzer1,250,175);
    }
}
```